# Are Hadoop 2.0 schedulers are working only for multi-users scenario?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, job-scheduling, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Are Fair and Capacity schedulers are working only when multiple users are submitting different jobs ? or they are working on the jobs submitted by one user as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Capacity and Fair schedulers are not user specific, even with one user it works. The same user can submit their jobs in different pools, queues in fair scheduler, capacity scheduler based on the resource required for jobs.